# When associating multiple sites to a new site, what about adding a minimum level reputation automatically for the new site?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reputation, new-users

I've been trying to lurk on the Programmer's site and a couple of other new Stack Exchange sites before posting a question to get a higher reputation.  My ID was automatically associated with my other Stack Exchange sites, but I still have under a 15 reputation on some of these sites.

So, I can't vote up questions or answers to show my interest in them, and don't feel comfortable adding answers to a question if I don't feel it will add value to the conversation.

It would be nice if a minimum level (15) reputation was automatically added when an ID is automatically linked.

Thanks,
Jeff

PS.  Arrgggg... can't post a second question right away, my retation is too low, so I have to wait for 20 minutes to ask this question.  This seems like a bad thing for the meta site.

Comment: +1 for coming up with an idea that's already in place :)  Just get that 200 on one site and then you should be good to go, with 101 on any other site that you associate or reassociate with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is already in place, but with different rep thresholds than you have in mind.

You have to have 200 rep on one of the sites you're associating your new account with in order to get the 100 rep association bonus on the new account.

As a workaround, you can get your rep up to 200 on one of your other sites and then disassociate/reassociate this account to receive the bonus.

Comment: Thanks this worked, finally got over 200 on a couple of accounts and got boosted on the other sites!